# html select tag with links that works after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html

I want a select tag , choose an option , click submit  , and go to a certain link . i found some solutions in here but wasn't what i was looking for , for example , some used onchange on select tag but it goes to the link before clicking the button , i look for  a solution with php or javascript (no jquery) .
this is what i tried , i don't know if it's correct or not . Please help, Thank you.

```
<form>
    <select class="custom-select" id="select" >
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option value="page1.php">1</option>
      <option value="page2.php">2</option>
      <option value="page3.php">3</option>
      <option value="page4.php">4</option>
    </select><br>
    <input class=" rech btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" type="submit" value="RECHERCHER" onClick="location=document.getElementById('select').value;"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: You mean you didn't test that code? Why not?

Comment: i did , it didn't work , but i don't know if the problem is the syntax  or the idea is wrong ..

Comment: Just to clarify what the issue was most likely: the `onclick` code runs, but right after, the browser reloads the page. That's because the form is sent, and without an `action` attribute, it's sent to the current location, essentially causing a page reload.

Comment: ah i see , Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll want to remove that **[`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)** event and make use of **[unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)** by adding an event listener to the `<form>`. Inside of this event listener, you'll want to trigger a function that passes through the event (`e` in the following example), so that you can prevent the default submission with **[`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)**.

Then you'll want to manually change the location with `window.location.href`, by simply passing through `select.value` to grab the value that was selected.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
const select = document.getElementById('select');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(select.value);
  // window.location.href = select.value;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <select class="custom-select" id="select">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="page1.php">1</option>
    <option value="page2.php">2</option>
    <option value="page3.php">3</option>
    <option value="page4.php">4</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <input class="rech btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" type="submit" value="RECHERCHER">
</form>
```

Comment: You can use `select.value`, there's no need to access the options array.

Comment: Thanks. Updated to simplify that :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! , but it shows me this message :/ :  TypeError: form is undefined"

Comment: ah it worked , i had to put the script after the form . thanks!